# Bitcoin unlimited nodes

Tags: transactions, nodes

What would happen if I try to broadcast a transaction being funded by segwit outputs with a bitcoin unlimited node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segwit transaction format is unknown for BU nodes. The peer either drop the connection or even ban your IP address for a while.

Comment: Wouldn't it just see it as anyone can spend and broadcast it?

Comment: Segwit transactions in "old" format are non-standard and are not relayed by default clients. Segwit transactions in "new" format are invalid for non-segwit clients

Comment: There is no ban for sending non-standard transactions, AFAIK.